# Passing multiple variables through json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm kinda making a mess now with my code, usually I'd make a PHP-AJAX script and pass one variable back to the JS script with json_encode. This time I would like to pass a few variables with json_encode, unfortunately I don't know how to separate the value in JS.

**My JS code:**

```
$('#submit').click(function(){

    // Storing the value into variables
    var content_page = $('#content-page').val();
    var content_url = 'action=saving&page='+content_page;

        // Starting the AJAX post form
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'handlers/content.handler.php',
                data: content_url,
                success: function(responseText)
                {
                    $.parseJSON(responseText); // Making the return value of the PHP handler reedable

                    alert(responseText.pageid)

                        if(responseText.indexOf(1) > -1)
                        {
                            noty({ text: 'U heeft geen pagina gekozen om te bewerken!' });
                        }
                        else if(responseText.indexOf(2) > -1)
                        {
                            noty({ text: 'U heeft geen geldige pagina gekozen!' }); 
                        }
                        else if(reponseText.indexOf(100) > -1)
                        {
                            noty({ text: 'Pagina is opgehaald' });
                        }
                }
            });
    return false;
});
```

**My PHP code:**

```
<?php
/* Dit bestand handeld gegevens af voor het bestand content in de map panel. Gegevens komen hier door heen via een JS bestand(content.handler.js...) en worden ook weer terug gestuurd. */
include_once '../includes/config.php';

    // Controleren of server contact maakt en geen persoon.
    if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'saving')
    {
        $stringPage = trim($_POST['page']);
        $error = array();
        $bolean = false;

            # Prepared statement.
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT id,name,title,text FROM pages WHERE name = ?');
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $stringPage);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result($pageID, $pageName, $pageTitle, $pageText);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $intPage = $stmt->num_rows();
            $stmt->close();

    /* Controle */
        if(empty($stringPage))
        {
            $error[] = 1;
            $bolean = true;
        }
        if($intPage == 0)
        {
            $error[] = 2;
            $bolean = true;
        }

            if($bolean == false)
            {
                $error[] = 100;

            }


            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            $array = array($error, $pageID, $pageName, $pageTitle, $pageText);
            echo json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    }
?>
```

So all the value is coming back just fine, so there's no problem with that. My problem is that I put everything that I wanted in an array(not the best solution) and don't know how to separate in JS. I suggest it would be something like response.pageid but that didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to parse the JSON first and assign to an object variable.  That's the only step you missed I think.

Also, returning a json encoded array is just fine.  I do it all the time.  You can add things like "status=success" and "errormessage=someerror"  so it comes in really handy.

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(response);
```

So in your case, you have the values in an array in php .. so lets say for example...

```
$myarray['fullname'] = 'john doe';
$myarray['userid'] = 777;
$myarray['isadmin'] = false;
$myarray['email'] = johndoe@gmail.com;
```

your ajax script then sends the response back to javascript ...

```
echo json_encode($myarray);
```

javascript gets it in your ajax success function ...

```
success: function (data) {
    var responsedata = $.parseJSON(data);

    alert('Fullname: '+responsedata.fullname+' userid: '+responsedata.userid+' isadmin: '+responsedata.isadmin);  //etc etc

}
```

**FROM CHAT**

I looked at your code on paste bin

use this to see the response btw

```
console.dir(responsetext); //instead of alert
```

or try firefox to do

```
alert(responsetext.toSource());
```

responsetext itself is an object and wont alert anything

think of response text as an array like in php, but instead of using `myarray['somekey']` you do `myobj.somekey`

change your error assignments to

```
error[1] , error[2], error[100]
```

instead of `error[]`

You are passing error to it, so that's an array, which you could access with `indexOf()` like you did, or you could use `textresponse.error[1]`

but your problem was the keys for the error array were just being assigned as 0, 1, 2 etc..

but you were trying to call them as 1,2,100 ...

so by adding those numbers instead of just using `error[]` it will now find the correct value when checking the error response.

Comment: Well thank you for responding that quickly. I'm already using the parseJSON option just after I declare my success function. But I will try your option of first assigning it as a variable. Thank you again!

Comment: No problem.  I do this all the time and you have to assign it to a variable, you could even use responsetext still like  responsetext = $.parseJSON(responsetext);

Comment: If it doesn't work for you there might be a larger issue so leave a comment here if it doesn't work so I can try to help you figure out what else might be the cause of your issue.  Thanks. :)

Comment: How did that work for you?  @RezaM if it was the correct answer can you click the checkmark to the left of my answer to indicate that.  Thanks !

Comment: I've accepted your answer, as it was right. But the problem still remains. I've used parseJSON as you can see in my code, but I've got multiple data passing trough. So if I do  $.parseJSON(responseText), I've got everything in one object. But how can I separate this? If I make a variable out of it, how do I recall it? Is it responsetext.error or how does that work? Thank you again for helping me with this!

Comment: Thank you, now everything is getting trough fine. If I may, I've still got one question, now that I can separate the values I can't find a way to use the data correctly to make an error notify. My current code(http://pastebin.com/cq8rgpF8), also when I alert the data variable I will get a null return. But if I check the console log from Chrome, then it's passing everything but not storing it right. Thank you for helping!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77052/discussion-between-notorious-pet0-and-rezam).

Comment: tried to get you in chat, I'll post my messages to the answer above